# Installed CocoaPods and Braintree now my project won't build

Tags: swift, xcode6, cocoapods, braintree

```
    Ld /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Podding-ffudeqoeybkocbevxvjrdlvtdswc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Podding.app/Podding normal x86_64
    cd /Users/admin/Development/zift/Podding
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.4
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.4.sdk -L/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Podding-ffudeqoeybkocbevxvjrdlvtdswc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/admin/Development/zift/Podding/Pods/Braintree/Braintree/PayPal/mSDK -F/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Podding-ffudeqoeybkocbevxvjrdlvtdswc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Podding-ffudeqoeybkocbevxvjrdlvtdswc/Build/Intermediates/Podding.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Podding.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Podding.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -lBraintree -lPayPalMobile-BT -lc++ -framework AVFoundation -framework Accelerate -framework AddressBook -framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreMedia -framework MessageUI -framework MobileCoreServices -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -weak_framework PassKit -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Podding-ffudeqoeybkocbevxvjrdlvtdswc/Build/Intermediates/Podding.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Podding.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Podding.swiftmodule -mios-simulator-version-min=8.4 -lPods -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Podding-ffudeqoeybkocbevxvjrdlvtdswc/Build/Intermediates/Podding.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Podding.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Podding_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Podding-ffudeqoeybkocbevxvjrdlvtdswc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Podding.app/Podding

duplicate symbol _llvm.cmdline in:
    /Users/admin/Development/zift/Podding/Pods/Braintree/Braintree/PayPal/mSDK/libPayPalMobile-BT.a(PPZebraAnalyticsWidgetCategories.o)
    /Users/admin/Development/zift/Podding/Pods/Braintree/Braintree/PayPal/mSDK/libPayPalMobile-BT.a(PP2FAViewController.o)
duplicate symbol _llvm.embedded.module in:
    /Users/admin/Development/zift/Podding/Pods/Braintree/Braintree/PayPal/mSDK/libPayPalMobile-BT.a(PPZebraAnalyticsWidgetCategories.o)
    /Users/admin/Development/zift/Podding/Pods/Braintree/Braintree/PayPal/mSDK/libPayPalMobile-BT.a(PP2FAViewController.o)
```

Those  last 2 "duplicate" lines repeat about a hundred times then this error

```
ld: 250 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I installed exactly how the CocoaPods site says. Using Xcode6 with swift.  I tried a bridging header still no success.  I tried using a brand new project as well same results. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by changing the build settings. Click the root of your project in Xcode and then view Build Settings.  Navigate to Linking and make sure you are showing "ALL" settings (top right area of build settings window).  Then remove Obj C from 'Other Linker Flags' as well as a setting $inherited.  I was able to clean and build.  Hope this helps.  I saw this answer somewhere else but I didnt figure it out since they didn't have the $inherited flag removed.